# Angular 10 is not working with windows 10

Tags: angular, powershell, windows-10, angular10

Error when ( ng serve ) As it is shown in the picture

[image]

thanks advance

Comment: Did you try running Unblock-File as suggested in the page at the URL provided in the error message you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the issue with the visual code terminal. Windows system is not allowing the vcode to run scripts in it's terminal. To give it access to run the scripts in the terminal you have to open vcode run as administrator. You can try running the same project in cmd then you will understand.

If run as administrator dont work then you have to change some settings in your visual studio code settings, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

[Vcode Settings Reference Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

***Hope this solves your issue, Happy Coding :)***